# Eclipse Project Error due to Facebook Library

Tags: android, facebook

I am having a strange error in my android project. I have integrated Facebook in my app. And it works nice. When I start eclipse, the eclipse show an error mark on my project which is due to dual inclusion of facebook library. I have included only the facebook API but it automatically includes com_facebook_android.jar file on eclipse startup. When I exclude this from my project, the error is removed. But when I start eclipse, it is again automatically included. I have also tried to delete com_facebook_android.jar file from my PC. It also gets generated automatically. Same is going on with my other projects having Facebook integrated.

[image]

Any idea ?

Comment: What does Eclipse say the problem is?

Comment: The error is:
Conversion to Dalvik format failed with error 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Delete the shared source folder.

Comment: The 'com_facebook_android_src' folder